# Mysql innodb database on wamp vs production

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, production-environment

i have 2 servers, one test one production.

1. Test - WAMP on Win7 (Intel i7 4GB Ram)
2. Production - IIS + FastCGI + MYSQL on Windows Server 2008 (Intel Xeon 2.4GHZ 12GB Ram)

We have an innodb database setup on both, and after deploying PHP source files, it would appear that a particular group of functions querying/displaying data from the database takes 100% LONGER on the production server.

On my test environment, I am seeing results come back after ~3 secs.
On production, it takes ~10 secs for exactly the same query, with exactly the same source files and same mirror of dbase.

If anything, I was expecting for timings to be reversed, ie production 100% faster than wamp. I checked my.ini files on both sides, and although they are not the same obviously there is nothing glaringly wrong in there which would cause this. I tested with a few different configs of my.ini on production and this had no effect in reducing the processing times.

The query used for this test is a complex multiple loop which interogates the database (sends one query, then loops through results and does further queries to mysql server on each row) All results are kept and modified in memory using multidimensional arrays.

I am timing the actual script execution only (mysql + php data retrieve and process), not the time it takes to send this data to the browser :)

Where should I look next?

Comment: Try and EXPLAIN the query. Then you can see how many data rows are being examined, what keys the server is deciding to use on each server and start by comparing the two outputs from EXPLAIN query

Comment: Also for your description it sounds like you should be using a join. 90% of the time if you use one query to fetch a data set and then loop over it to query additional information youre doing wrong :-)

Comment: I do not think "explain" will be of any use - both test & production have got exactly the same database, same structure, same data,same everything. The only difference is wamp is MYSQL 5.5.20 and production is MYSQL 5.5.14.

I understand using a join will make everything run faster, this is not the question however, I want to know why is my wamp server faster than the production server. To me it stinks of a wrong configuration on production, or possibly due to the fact its all running on windows?
From past experience, anything I ran on wamp was usually 50% slower than on production server

Answer (score 0):

just to close this, it was due to the incorrect localisation within php environment - setting my locale at the top of the php page cured the problem. 
(despite it being correctly set within php.ini, IIS slowed down when performing date based functions)
love microsoft

Comment: Thanks for leaving a follow-up! I'm sure someone will benefit from this one day :)